# Unable to overriding a css element in responsive design

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blogger

This is the [problematic Link](http://www.secondgf.com/). I have an element called `tbox` in CSS. It is an inline box having width:100%. On the homepage it adjusts its width according to its parent perfectly and is perfectly responsive, but when I enter into the post, its width changes according to the content inside. Here are some 
[screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkOeW.jpg)

And this is the post, when I open it-

This is the code for `tbox`

```
.tbox{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 25px;

}
```

When I change the width to 850px, it works well on desktop but I can't override the width in responsive design. It always remains 850px.

So how to make it responsive, if the width is 850px? Or is there any other solution?

Comment: There's nothing there with that dimension. Is it a parent element causing problems?

Comment: plz add some more details, what u want to achieve here??

Comment: I reckon you check the width of its parent container in your post page. Make sure that has a width: 100% too. Else you should look into media queries

Comment: try use with `min-width and max-width`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with `tbox` search your code for `.item .post.hentry` and change `width: 850px;` to `max-width: 850px;`

```
.item .post.hentry {
    max-width: 850px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use media query for responsive as like and this code must write bellow main css as like first your main css

```
.tbox{
display: inline-block;
width: 90%; // change it as you want
height: auto;
padding: 2px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border-radius: 25px;
}
```

then write above code bellow

```
@media (max-width:780px) { 
.tbox{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%; // change it as you want
 height: auto;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 25px;
  } 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `box-sizing` property in `.tbox` class -

```
.tbox {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 25px;
    box-sizing: border-box; // add this property in main css
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try writing media queries like this ,then your div will be responsive

```css
.tbox{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 25px;

}

@media(max-width:767px) {
 .tbox{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 90%; //change percentage here
    height: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 25px;

    }
}

@media (max-width:1024px) and (min-width:768px) {
 .tbox{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%; //change percentage here
    height: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 25px;

    }
}

@media (max-width:414px) and (min-width:100px) {
 .tbox{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70%; //change percentage here
    height: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 25px;

    }
}
```